# Alternative test

Tags: wilcoxon-signed-rank, fishers-exact-test

I am doing a peer review. The article is about the effect o[image]f yokukansan (YKS) on behavioral and psychological symptoms of Alzheimer disease. There were 15 patients, divided into 2 groups: the treatment group has 10 and the control has 5. The Neuropsychiatric Inventory was used to measure the symptoms, and was measured every 4 weeks. The test being used here is Wilcoxon test. Is there an alternative testfor this? 
Thank you. [image]

Comment: why are you peer reviewing a paper that you don't understand? pass it on to someone else.

Comment: Why would you need to identify an alternative test?  (Also, did you notice the spelling errors in the table?)

Comment: This peer review is part of my course
As in here the authors want to compare two groups at multiple time points (baseline, 4wk,8wk,12wk) so using a Wilcoxon test is not going to answer the research question